# Mi red neuronal convolucional no entrena

Tags: python, tensorflow, redes-neuronales, keras, inteligencia-artificial

estoy programando una red neuronal convolucional para detectar un tipo de imágenes, quiero que me diga si una imagen pertenece a una clase o no, pero a la hora de ejecutar el entrenamiento se me queda cargando pero no hace nada, estas son mis especificaciones de equipo:

- GPU: Nvidia RTX 2080 super
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 9 3900X
- RAM: 64GB
- Tensorflow: 2.4
- python3
- Windows

el código de mi red neuronal es el siguiente:

```
# To add a new cell, type'
# To add a new markdown cell, type [markdown]'
import os
import zipfile
import math
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import keras
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Model, Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.applications import VGG16


print('GPU available:', tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))
print('tensorflow version:',tf.__version__)
print('keras version:', tf.keras.__version__)


path = './pruebaContador.jpg'
img = image.load_img(path)
data = image.img_to_array(img)
samples = np.expand_dims(data, 0)


datagen = image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=40,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode='nearest'
)


it = datagen.flow(samples, batch_size = 1)

for i in range(6):
  plt.subplot(230 + 1 + i)
  batch = it.next()
  image = batch[0].astype('uint8')
  plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()


base_dir = './dataset'

train_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'train')
test_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'test')


train_cont_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, 'contador')
train_no_cont_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, 'no_contador')

test_cont_dir = os.path.join(test_dir, 'contador')
test_no_cont_dir = os.path.join(test_dir, 'no_contador')


train_cont_fnames = os.listdir(train_cont_dir)
train_no_cont_fnames = os.listdir(train_no_cont_dir)

print('train_cont:', train_cont_fnames[:5])
print('train_no_cont:', train_no_cont_fnames[:5])


print('total training cont images :', len(os.listdir(train_cont_dir)))
print('total training no_cont images :', len(os.listdir(train_no_cont_dir)))
print()
print('total test cont images :', len(os.listdir(test_cont_dir)))
print('total test no_cont images :', len(os.listdir(test_no_cont_dir)))


def create_model():
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', input_shape = (150, 150, 3)))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
    
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
    
    model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
    
    model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
    
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(512, activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
    
    return model


model = create_model()
model.summary()


my_optimizer = RMSprop(lr = 1e-4)


model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = my_optimizer, metrics = ['acc'])
 

train_datagen = image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1./255,
    rotation_range = 40,
    width_shift_range = 0.2,
    height_shift_range = 0.2,
    shear_range = 0.2,
    zoom_range = 0.2,
    horizontal_flip = True,
    fill_mode = 'nearest'
)


test_datagen = image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1.0/255.)


train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir, batch_size = 20, class_mode = 'binary', target_size = (150, 150))


test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(test_dir, batch_size = 20, class_mode = 'binary', target_size = (150, 150))


batch_size = 20
EPOCHS = 10


history = model.fit(train_generator, epochs = EPOCHS, verbose = 1)


dir = './model/'

if not os.path.exists(dir):
    os.mkdir(dir) 
    
model.save('./model/model.h5')
model.save_weights('./model/pesos.h5')
```

al ejecutarlo se me ha quedado petado en Epoch 1/10 y lleva un buen rato así, ni si quiera me saca la información de en que iteración está, ya que tengo puesto verbose = 1, y no logro encontrar donde esta el error, ¿Alguien sabe que podría ser y como solucionarlo? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Cómo instalaste el tensorflow? Desde pip o conda? Sí estás en windows y usaste PIP, estás seguro de tener cuda instalado y configurado? La demora puede ser que estás corriendo solo en CPU.

Comment: ya logré solucionarlo, el problema era que tenía mal instalado cuDNN